# update static variable in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, static-variables

I am working on a program for playing background audio for Windows Phone 8 with c#.
My solution contains 2 projects: Main project and AudioPlaybackAgent project.

1. In AudioPlaybackAgent, I add static variable `currentTrackNumber` with
   get and set in file "AudioPlayer.cs":

   ```
   namespace AudioPlaybackAgent
   {
       public class AudioPlayer : AudioPlayerAgent
       {
           static int currentTrackNumber = 0;

           ...
           ...

           public static int CurrentTrackNumber
           {
               get { return currentTrackNumber; }
               set { currentTrackNumber = value; }
           }

           ...
           ...

       }
   }
   ```
2. In Main project, I try to update the static variable in file
   "MainPage.xaml.cs" by adding:

   ```
   namespace Main_Project
   {
       public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
       {

            ...
            ...

            private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                AudioPlaybackAgent.AudioPlayer.CurrentTrackNumber = myValue;  
            }

            ...
            ...

       }
   }
   ```

But the variable is not changing. Why?

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of static variables that they don't change?

Comment: @Kickaha : Maybe you are confused between `static` and `constant`. Please see [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan Thanks :)

Comment: @Developer have you try with this `internal static int currentTrackNumber = 0;`

Answer (score 2):

The projects are running in separate processes, so they have separate copies of the static. You typically get basic information like track changes etc. via the Agent methods that you override. If you need more information (like arbitrary skipping into a playlist) then you can signal with a file and an IPC mechanism like Win32 events -- see [this post and associated sample](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/03/27/using-named-events-to-coordinate-foreground-apps-and-background-agents/).

This gets better with Universal Windows apps since there is a direct way to signal messages back and forth via the [BackgroundMediaPlayer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.backgroundmediaplayer.aspx).